# How can I identify invisible online tracking images?

Tags: privacy, user-tracking, image

This question refers to invisible 1 pixel images that are placed on web pages to track you via how your browser renders the image. Is there any potential way to discover these images despite them being supposedly invisible?  One solution I've considered is using a browser extension that lets you outline images or display their alt attribute. Will this work, or is there another solution?

Comment: If you mean 1x1 tracking GIFs, I'm sure there are extensions that look for those specifically. Note that even when doing that, there are _countless_ other ways to track someone, even to the point of fingerprinting their hardware to perfectly uniquely identify them (e.g. with AudioContext fingerprinting).

Comment: @forest I am aware of the several other methods of online tracking , I just felt that I had a less definitive strategy for dealing with the images.

Comment: Is this a purely academic adventure? Short of using Tor browser with scripting disabled, there is no effective way to mitigate online tracking of this sort (it requires either hardware modifications or heavy patches to the core of the browser). You can try to detect 1x1 GIFs, but there is no _reason_ to do so.

Comment: @forest I simply value my personal privacy and have an interest in improving it in any way that I can, but I have no serious need for it, so I have a balance between security and convenience that doesn't entail using Tor (while I could if the need arose) but includes extensions like script blockers. So, yes, it's basically an academic adventure.

Comment: As long as you are aware that this will _reduce_ your personal privacy by reducing your anonymity set... But if it truly is purely academic, it should be possible to write some JS to detect or block GIF images with 1x1 dimensions, or any of the multiple "block clear GIFs" browser plugins.